# Masonry layout clearing issue

Tags: masonry

I am using Masonry - the HTML version

I have a div:

```
<div id="container" class="js-masonry" data-masonry-options='{ "itemSelector": ".item"}'>
```

within I have about 10:

```
            <div class="item">
                <img src="<?php the_field('image'); ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                <p></p>
                <a style="text-decoration:underline;" class="link-port" href="<?php the_field('link'); ?>" target="_blank"><?php  the_title();?></a>
                <p></p>
            </div>
```

The problem is that when the page loads first time (uncached) the first few items show normally, but further down the page they stack on top of each other. They also overlap the footer.
If you either refresh the browser (or rotate the device) then all works fine but this is obviously not ideal for new visitors.

The JS was at the bottom of the page, but I moved to the top and it still did the same.

Has anyone come across this before?

Many thanks.

Comment: I imagine you can see it here http://liquidengine.com/portfolio/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha! imagesLoaded seems to be the answer, full details here: http://masonry.desandro.com/appendix.html#imagesloaded